# What is "to have a run of accidents"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is "to have a run of accidents"?

> Miss Lowe **had a run of accidents** before her birthday, spending a week in hospital after a fall at home and suffering whiplash in a car accident while being driven to her nephew’s house.

Comment: Please see [A Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for more tips on formatting, titling, and asking your questions.

Comment: As a reminder, you are expected to demonstrate your initial attempts at research when posing a question on Stack Exchange. For example, looking up *[run](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run_2#run_2__7)* in a dictionary should give you some ideas as to its use here.

Answer (score 2):

A run of similar events is a series of events of that type. The term is often, but not always, used about unfortunate events, e.g. a run of bad luck.

Comment: Thank you and "to suffer whiplash" means a neck injury caused by the head suddenly moving forwards and then back again, for example in a car accident or it means sudden onset (attack) of some disease?

Comment: @Jane - Please don't ask follow-on questions in comments. If you wanted to know about both phrases, you should have asked in your question. You can also open another question about "suffer whiplash," but you should look the words up in a dictionary first and tell us what you found. People asking questions on SE are expected to do and share a modicum of research.